# Find $f\circ g$, where $f, g : A \to A$ with $A=\{x, y, z\}$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, function-and-relation-composition

I have been solving similar questions and got them right, except this one where the answer in the back of the book doesn't match mine. The question goes:

**Exercise.** Find $f\circ g$, where $f, g : A \to A$ with $A=\{x, y, z\}$ and $f,g$ are defined by $f = \{(x,y),(y,z),(z,x)\}$ and $g = \{(x,y),(y,x),(z,z)\}$.

Answer in the back says, it's $\{(x,x),(y,z),(z,y)\}$ whereas I'm getting $\{(x,z),(y,y),(z,x)\}$. Could someone please help?

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: The book answer is $g\circ f$

Comment: Are you defining $f\circ g$ as $f(g)$ or $g(f)$?

Comment: Thank you guys so much, I've been scratching my head for over half an hour now. If I could attach a pic in the comments it clearly says  f∘g not vice versa, but I'm guessing it's a printing mistake? Thanks a lot

Comment: @JohnDouma f∘g as f(g), I mean get g first then use answer for f

Comment: That is not universal. When I was in school I was taught that $f\circ g$ was equal to $g(f)$, i.e. $f$ then $g$. How does your book define it?

Comment: @JohnDouma it's defined as f∘g=f(g(x)), g then f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f\circ g=f(g(x))$, then

- $x\xrightarrow{g}y\xrightarrow{f}z$,
- $y\xrightarrow{g}x\xrightarrow{f}y$,
- $z\xrightarrow{g}y\xrightarrow{f}x$,

and hence $f\circ g=\{(x,z),(y,y),(z,x)\}$. And if $f\circ g=g(f(x))$, then

- $x\xrightarrow{f}y\xrightarrow{g}x$,
- $y\xrightarrow{f}z\xrightarrow{g}z$,
- $z\xrightarrow{f}y\xrightarrow{g}y$,

and hence $f\circ g=\{(x,x),(y,z),(z,y)\}$. So the result depends on the definition of $f\circ g$. By the way, we usually define $f\circ g=f(g(x))$.

Comment: Thank you so much. In my book, it's defined as f∘g=f(g(x)). So, I guess we have to do it that way. Thanks again